# Showing icons to represent content types

Tags: 7, nodes, theming

Is there a simple way to have the site display a content type icon just before the "Submitted by..." function? I know I can do this conditionally in node.tpl.php like

```
if ($type==blog_post) echo '<img src=blog_post.png />';
```

etc. But this seems cumbersome. I have seen this done as part of Drupal Commons and others. Is there a module that can handle this or any other systematic changes to how the metadata is displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is set up by the node.module via preprocess()ing in variables:

```
// Display post information only on certain node types.
if (variable_get('node_submitted_' . $node->type, TRUE)) {
  $variables['display_submitted'] = TRUE;
  $variables['submitted'] = t('Submitted by !username on !datetime', array('!username' => $variables['name'], '!datetime' => $variables['date']));
  $variables['user_picture'] = theme_get_setting('toggle_node_user_picture') ? theme('user_picture', array('account' => $node)) : '';
}
else {
  $variables['display_submitted'] = FALSE;
  $variables['submitted'] = '';
  $variables['user_picture'] = '';
}
```

These are then used like this in (the standard core) node.tpl.php:

```
<?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
  <div class="submitted">
    <?php print $submitted; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So, it would be pretty easy to do something along these lines in your theme's `template.php` file:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

  if ($variables['display_submitted']) {
    $variables['submitted']='<img class="submitted-node-type" src="' . $variables['node']->type . '.jpg">' . $variables['submitted']; // or whatever/however you want to do this
  }

  // any other preprocessing goes here

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I know how to make template and CSS changes, but haven't dabbled into functions yet. This goes in template.php, right?

Comment: Yes, inside template.php with `YOURTHEME` being changed accordingly as well :)

Answer (score 1):

All content types have CSS classes (in body tag if you are viewing the node or in container tag of the teaser). You can use them to add background image to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, I may do this if I can't get the function above to work. I'd prefer to be able to have the text name of the content type as well as the icon.

Comment: You can use `some-element:after {content:"content name"}`. Personally I like to do as match in CSS as possible - easier to change and maintain. But YMMV :-).

Comment: That sounds pretty good, and may be more up my alley than overriding the function. Thanks so much!